# Is there way to ignore not-found system function in a kernel .sys module? so to run .sys in older Windows

Tags: windows-kernel, kmdf, windows-driver

I'm facing such a problem. I've built a Windows kernel mode driver using WDK11, and, in order to pass Windows 11 WHQL, I need to use new memory allocating function [ExAllocatePool2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-exallocatepool2). The problem is, this driver will fail to load on Windows 7.

[image: Win7 driver loading fail (Code 39)]

[image: Depends shows that ExAllocatePool2 is not available on Win7]

You know, Win7 does not have `ExAllocatePool2`, just like a user-mode EXE cannot find a new-era API in a system DLL on an older Windows OS, so the EXE fails to run.

For a user mode EXE, I can use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` trick to dynamically detect that new-era API is not available at runtime, so that I can fall back to call older API.

I think the same idea applies to kernel mode, using `RtlIsNtDdiVersionAvailable` to probe for OS version, then call best available API from the system. But how to do **real** runtime dynamic linking to desired API?

Or, if there is a way to tell the system to ignore `ExAllocatePool2` resolving errors when loading my .sys, the question is considered resolved as well.

In one word, the requirement is, I want to have a single binary to support all of Win11/Win10/Win7, and use new APIs on new OS.

Comment: [MmGetSystemRoutineAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-mmgetsystemroutineaddress), perfectly documented and available since Windows 2000.

Comment: Thank you. You're right. Please paste it as answer.